# Sending network request using switchMap android

Tags: android, rx-java2

Say I want to send from my android app a network request when user hit a button. 
I'm using RxJava and since I want to cancel the previous request if user hit send request again I need to use swithcMap like the following:

```
buttonClickObservable.map(e -> searchTextView.getText().toString())
                     .switchMap(searchText -> sendNetworkRequestToServer(searchText));
```

what happens if it takes to request to be processed on the server few second and in the meantime the user clicks the button agains. As far as I understand the first observable will be disposed and a new network call will be generated but the server already started to process the first one so I see that switchMap doesn't help me here?

Comment: when sever received called, so you cannot cancel this, you only can cancel response.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to simply disable the button when the request is in progress and enable it when it completes or errors.

pseudocode:

```
buttonClickObservable.map(e -> searchTextView.getText().toString())
            .doOnNext(e -> buttonClickView.setEnabled(false))
            .switchMap(searchText -> sendNetworkRequestToServer(searchText));
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    result -> ...,
                    error -> buttonClickView.setEnabled(true),
                    () -> buttonClickView.setEnabled(true)
            )
```

However this solution is not ideal. I think what you are looking for is to follow the MVI architecture and manage the state properly. If you are interested this is a great talk to watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IKHxjkgop4